# How to Use Google Input Tools in Website

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please let me know if it is possible to use Google Input Tools in a website using client side scripting like jquery or pure javascript? Is there any API available for Google Input Tools?

I already google this but couldn't find any thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 33):

If you want to add google input tools you can use below code to add it

```js
    
      // Load the Google Transliteration API
      google.load("elements", "1", {
        packages: "transliteration"
      });
    
      function onLoad() {
        var options = {
          sourceLanguage: 'en',
          destinationLanguage: ['gu', 'ml', 'hi', 'kn', 'ta', 'te'],
          shortcutKey: 'ctrl+m',
          transliterationEnabled: true
        }
    
        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required options.
        var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
    
        // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.
        var ids = ["language"];
        control.makeTransliteratable(ids);
    
        // Show the transliteration control which can be used to toggle between English and Hindi and also choose other destination language.
        control.showControl('translControl');
      }
    
      google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  
<textarea name="hi"  rows="6"  id="language" cols="6" style="width:600px;height:70px" ></textarea>

<div id='translControl'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps me. But i found one problem with this, it only suggests the word after stroke "Space bar" , Is it possible to listout suggestion on every key stroke?

Comment: I am using this in jquery and its not working properly

Comment: This answer gives example of transliteration api instead of using IME (input method editor). Transliteration refers to the method of mapping from one system of writing to another based on phonetic similarity. For example, in Hindi transliteration, you can type in "namaste" to get "नमस्ते", which sounds like "namaste". Input Method Editors (IMEs) convert keystrokes to characters in another language.

Comment: Good its works fine but my issue is to use this script more than one time in same page?

Comment: @SanjayaPandey: Did you find any solution? (suggestion on every key stroke) I badly need this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Iam using this code in all my website. To enable this I had spend day of effort because my client need to add regional language website, so I have gone though many websites and they all are not able to integrate so finally I taken google input tool and the code was very easy to use if you are using global header in admin add the java code in header and only required pages text editor you need to add the id-language" tag Suppor TinyMCE, ckeditor etc.

Comment: If any one want to use the code more than one time in the page you in the text area you only need to add the id="language" . IF you are it was not working post your code here or share you  stack link I will look it and try to help you.

Comment: It will work in both mobile and desktop. check if you included required paths

Answer (score 5):

Pravathy's answer worked for me as well. Just adding following google docs url if someone looks more details.

[Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started)