# how to use google transliteration in website with keyboard enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I follow this methods to add [google transliteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707899/how-to-use-google-input-tools-in-website) in my website. As in offline version of google input tools, we can enable keyboard. Is there any way to enable such keyboard in website too? And also, instead of adding shortcuts key to toggle how can i add button to toggle?