# How to use google input tools in my website

Tags: javascript, google-input-tools

I had find the code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707899/how-to-use-google-input-tools-in-website)

and having same code but it's not working.
It's saying me

```
The page at 'https://suryaprakashanmandir.com/something.php'was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.google.com/inputtools/request?text=hello&ime=transliteration_en_ml&num=5&cp=0&cs=0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=jsapi&uv&cb=_callbacks_._0k5mbnkfb'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

My full code of something.php is like:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Google Transliterate API
  google.load("elements", "1", {
        packages: "transliteration"
      });

  function onLoad() {
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage:
            google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage:
            [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };

    // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
    // options.
    var control =
        new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

    // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
    // 'transliterateTextarea'.
    control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
</script>
<textarea id="transliterateTextarea" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>
```

I have a .htaccess file in my root folder like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^suryaprakashanmandir\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.suryaprakashanmandir.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Try changing the URL to "http**s**://www.google.com"?

Comment: now it's giving me google is not defined on google.load

Comment: Google is not defined? May you add a [mcve] of your code, and the error you're seeing to the question (not as a comment)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Please review the updated question